# Display an image in a label without saving it

Tags: python, image, opencv, pyqt5, qpixmap

The following lines are in my script:

```
    from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
    from PyQt5.Widgets import *
    import cv2
```

```
imgCross = positioningCross(Dy, Dx, center, imgCross)
cv2.imwrite("img.png", imgCross)
self.ImgLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap("img.png"))
```

def positioningCross(Dy, Dx, center, imgCross):
    if(center[1,0]>=center[0,0]):
        Dy2 = center[0,0] + np.absolute(Dy)
    else:
        Dy2 = center[1,0] + np.absolute(Dy)

`if(center[0,1]>=center[1,1]):
        Dx2 = center[1,1] + np.absolute(Dx)/2
    else:
        Dx2 = center[0,1] + np.absolute(Dx)/2

    P1 = (center[0,1]/2,center[0,0]/2)
    P2 = (center[1,1]/2,center[1,0]/2)
    P3 = (Dx2/2,Dy2/2+100)
    P4 = (Dx2/2,Dy2/2-100)

    cv2.line(imgCross,(int(P1[0]),int(P1[1])),(int(P2[0]),int(P2[1])),(0,0,255),1)
    cv2.line(imgCross,(int(P3[0]),int(P3[1])),(int(P4[0]),int(P4[1])),(0,0,255),1)
    imgCross= cv2.flip(imgCross,1)
    return imgCross`

I want to paint two lines with positioningCross into imgCross and display it in a label of my GUI.
At the moment, I'm saving the modified image in a folder, but I want to know if it is possible to add it to the Label without saving it?

My solution is ok, but I guess it could be better

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is a bit incomplete, but the following should show you how to do what you want.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
label = QLabel()
pixmap = QPixmap(32, 32)
painter = QtGui.QPainter(pixmap)
# Now draw whatever you like on the pixmap..no need to save to file
painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.red)
painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.white))
rect = QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 31, 31)
painter.drawRect(rect)
painter.drawText(rect, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter, "foo")
painter.end()
label.setPixmap(pixmap)

label.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```